# selecting items by class inside element on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to pick all the child `.preview` elements inside `.dropzone` parent.

```
$('.dropzone').add($('.preview')).length
```

This returns 3 but there are 2 objects. I guess it is counthing also the `.dropzone` container.

How can I choose only the two `.preview` items?

Comment: Please check the jQuery documentation before you post here. http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Demo please: http://jsfiddle.net/KjJZx/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/wbkVS/

API: http://api.jquery.com/children/ `Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector`

Hope it fits the need! `:)`

**Code**

`$('.dropzone').children('.preview').length`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.dropzone').find('.preview').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Common selector syntax for selecting this would just be:

`$('.dropzone .preview').length` or

`$('.dropzone > .preview).length` (if it is a direct child of `.dropzone`)

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

@Igor's answer also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct it is also counting the container div. Use the CSS descendant selector (and empty space between elements) within the jQuery function to select the descendants of the element (descendants are all elements inside the element).

```
$('.dropzone .preview').length === 2
```

Or, if you only want children (direct descendants), use the child selector (>).

```
$('.dropzone > .preview').length === 2
```

The add function adds to the current elements in the jQuery object, just as you suspected.